# The entity type 'Child' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core 2 I have the following entities:

```
public class Parent {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
  public Int32 ParentId { get; set; }
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I want Parent and Child to have a One to One relationship.

And I want ParentId to be both FK and PK of entity Child ...

So I tried the following configuration:

```
builder.Entity<Parent>().ToTable("Parents");
builder.Entity<Parent>().Property(y => y.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();    

builder.Entity<Child>().ToTable("Childs");
builder.Entity<Child>().HasOne(x => x.Parent)
                       .WithOne(x => x.Child)
                       .HasForeignKey<Child>(x => x.ParentId);
```

But I get the following error:

```
The entity type 'Child' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: As usual when the PK name doesn't match the conventions - `builder.Entity<Child>().HasKey(x => x.ParentId);`.

Comment: I tried that before and I keep getting the same error ...

Comment: Try again? :) Should work. And no way to work without it.

Comment: Yes, after all it works. I was missing adding one of the entities to the model. You can add your answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing in common with relationships.

Simply `ParentId` does not match the [key property name conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#conventions), hence needs to be specified with data annotations

```
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

or fluent API

```
builder.Entity<Child>().HasKey(x => x.ParentId);
```